# Sequelize fetching data from a column which is not specified in models

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize for mysql in node js.I have a table which has more than 20 columns in it , but I have created a model for it in sequelize with only 5 columns , so now when I give find all , I will get only those 5 attributes in my result , but when I use findone and in the where condition if I give a column which is not specified in the model(out of the 5 attributes) , still its working fine , instead of throwing an error , is this expected scenario ???

My model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var orders = sequelize.define('orders', {
        id:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey : true
        },
        cust: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),
        name: DataTypes.TEXT,
        status: DataTypes.TEXT,
        order_placed_on: DataTypes.DATE  
     },{
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });

     return orders;
};
```

My function code where i'm accessing the data through this query "findOne".

```
      let data = await this.model.findOne({
        where:         {
          id: "12345"
        },
        attributes : ["portal"]
      });
```

I thought it should throw error like "invalid column name" as portal is not specified in the model , but its working as expected , is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: Did you enable option `sequelize.sync({ force: true })` ( Note: It will recreate whole database and you will lose data ) or "alter:true"  so your database which is already created and the changes you made now should be consistent.

Comment: No , I haven't used them because i'm making use of a common db which is used by many , so i thought of just using the same schema ...